# Software to find cover art for different mp3 in group

Tags: music, mp3

I want to ask you for advice some soft to automatically find cover arts for mp3 files.

I tried to use MP3tag, but its not very good solution for me, because it is adjusted to work with whole albums. I have my music libraries in larger folders, mixed everything possible :)

The second software I found is "MP3 CoverTag", but this one is even too much simple. It has only one button to automatically do everything, and I have no option to select better or proper picture for specific song neither take action if program detect it wrong. But I was suprised, after process, most of songs had right image, so source database is good.

So, I need something with good database, where I can see previews and select which one should be downloaded, and, of course, picture must be inserted into mp3 file as tag, not just downloaded to folder as cover.jpg or similarly.

I hope something exists, because I was looking google and I didnt found anything :/ So Thanks very much if you advise me smtg :)

Answer (score 0):

wow, i'm impressed of activity in this forum :D 
I have found this:
http://www.creevity.com
and it's absolutely perfect solution to my problem. I warmly recomend it to everyone who will want to update covers in his mp3 collections :)

Comment: This post together with the question  and product link are surely an attempt by the poster to promote their own product without declaring their interest.

Answer (score 0):

I have use jaikoz for many years, and I neither work for nor accept anything free from them.  In fact, it is one of the few things I willing renew the yearly subscription.

http://www.jthink.net/jaikoz/

It also handles other audio formats not limited but including FLAC.